Can angle valves point to any direction without causing issues?
I just installed angle valve with a 1/2 inch male thread in order to install my washing machine inlet hose, the valve opens and closes up by turning the knob 90 degrees. It is very similar to this one:

The problem I am facing right now is that I could not tighten the valve anymore, and the direction it ended up pointing was towards the walls, actually 3-4 degrees upwards, not towards the ground:

I still can turn the knob, so that is not an issue, and the washing machine inlet hose has no issues with that position since it also bends nicely, similarly to this:

I am not sure if all angled valves are made the same, but the last one I had had a plastic ball inside, while this one seems to have had something metal inside that turned when I turned the knob, not sure if it was a ball or not, it just closed/opened gradually.
So I was wondering if there will be any issues in the long run, I have installed it an hour ago, and at this moment there are no issues with it.

@crip659: Looks like an answer, especially if you add the point about extreme tightening not being necessary (especially with pipe tape) so it might actually be possible to rotate the valve back to the desired orientation while still being watertight.

I see then, I've replied there, but yeah I guess this is the optimal angle to leave it on, since anything else is either too loose or not possible to use. Btw, I've used hemp, and where I live, there is no paste sold since it's not widely used. Maybe this was one of the reasons why it got so tight, but had no other option.

Valves and water do not really care.
Most are pointed down just because it is easier to fill a bucket/sink.
With a hose on it, the direction is just for looks.
As Keshlam pointed out, most threaded fittings have a range of turning and not leaking, around a half turn from very tight.  Having it too tight is not good and might cause a leak by damaging the threads/pipe.

This is more optimal than pointing upwards, or on the left side, and the tightness came suddenly around when the valve was pointing somewhere upwards. So I guess this is the most optimal place to be.

(Nitpick: for looks and to be clear of obstructions. Having the tap point at a wall just a few inches away would be awkward, though compact  L-fittings for hoses do exist.)
